# Can't drop rows with empty list whilst taking the mean of the other lists

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series `df` that has 2 columns. I am attempting to drop all the empty lists from `yearly_cost` columns whilst taking an average of the lists containing floats to create a singular value for each individual day. There are multiple values for the same date in `date` column and therefore I am trying to merge all rows based on the date. `df` looks as such:

```
    date        yearly_cost
0   2009-01-01  []
1   2009-01-02  [409.45,294.33,394.56]
2   2009-01-03  [403.45,175.30,323.67]
3   2009-01-01  [456.34,355.3,493.5]
4   2009-01-02  []
5   2009-01-03  [295.39, 439.23]
```

Some days will have multiple lists and therefore I need to take an average over both lists to create a single value.

I have attempted to use `.dropna()`, `np.nanmean()` and average the lists with `ts.yearly_cost = [np.mean(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in ts.yearly_cost]` with concatenating by date 
 with `.set_index('date').mean(axis=1).reset_index(name='Yearly_Cost')` which has worked for time series in the past without empty lists.

I wish for the end result to look as such:

```
date        yearly_cost
0   2009-01-01  435.05
1   2009-01-02  366.11
2   2009-01-03  327.408
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: couple of questions: why are your yearly costs associated with days? why are you storing lists in data frame elements? dataframe work much better with scalars in each row/column

Answer (score 4):

If there are lists in column `yearly_cost` first flatten them and then aggregate `mean`:

```
import ast
#necessary if string repr of lists
#df['yearly_cost'] = df['yearly_cost'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'yearly_cost' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['yearly_cost'].tolist())), 
    'date' : df['date'].values.repeat(df['yearly_cost'].str.len())
})

df = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['yearly_cost'].mean()
print (df)
         date  yearly_cost
0  2009-01-01   435.046667
1  2009-01-02   366.113333
2  2009-01-03   327.408000
```

Another solution:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df['yearly_cost'].values.tolist(), index=df['date']).stack()
df = s.mean(level=0).reset_index(name='yearly_cost')
print (df)
         date  yearly_cost
0  2009-01-02   366.113333
1  2009-01-03   327.408000
2  2009-01-01   435.046667
```

Comment: I receive the following error on the first step `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: Also another problem is that the third date has the sum of two average rather than a single average of the whole day.

Comment: @geds133 - yes, so changed solution

Comment: I have just received `MemoryError: `

Comment: @geds133 how big is your data?

Comment: @piRSquared only 300,000 rows

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

Drop the empty list by convert the type to bool.

```
df=df[df.yearly_cost.astype(bool)].copy()
```

After drop the empty list , you can do `groupby`

```
df.groupby('date')['yearly_cost'].apply(lambda x : np.mean(x.sum()))
```

Comment: Receive the same error as above `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: @geds133 you need to let us know if the `'yearly_cost'` column are strings or lists.

Comment: @piRSquared Empty lists and lists with floats in

Answer (score 0):

#### `groupby.sum` and `np.mean`

The sum will concatenate the lists.

```
df.groupby('date').yearly_cost.sum().apply(np.mean)

date
2009-01-01    435.046667
2009-01-02    366.113333
2009-01-03    327.408000
Name: yearly_cost, dtype: float64
```

If those are strings

```
from ast import literal_eval

df.yearly_cost.apply(literal_eval).groupby(df.date).sum().apply(np.mean)
```

---

#### ALT

```
df.groupby('date').yearly_cost.apply(lambda x: np.concatenate([*x]).mean())
```

---

#### Factorize

```
i, u = df.date.factorize()
j = i.repeat([*map(len, df.yearly_cost)])
v = np.concatenate(df.yearly_cost)

c = np.bincount(j)
s = np.bincount(j, v)
pd.Series(s / c, u)

2009-01-01    435.046667
2009-01-02    366.113333
2009-01-03    327.408000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I spoke too soon, there still seem to be empty lists within the time series as when I try and create a moving average I get this error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[]'`

Comment: @geds133 I get that when I do `float('[]')` which means that you have strings in your data which is contrary to what you've claimed.  This means you have bad data and need to clean it.  Several users have suggested `literal_eval`.  Prior to using one of the techniques, try doing this `df['yearly_cost'] = df['yearly_cost'].astype(str).apply(literal_eval)`.  Make sure to `from ast import literal_eval`

Comment: Is it possible that the empty lists are counted as strings? The returned `df` is a series with `date` as the index and no `yearly_cost`.